# Suddenly unable to run Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Today, I start to use Flutter with VSCode as editor and started debugging, the errors printed as follows and found not able to fix this. I find some articles that I should do `flutter clean` command but actually it was not resolved. Please kindly advise me to how to resolve this problem.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
Unhandled exception:
Crash when compiling null,
at character offset null:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1
#0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:264:36)
#1      Class.superclassConstraints (package:kernel/ast.dart:1089:73)
#2      SourceClassBuilder.checkMixinApplication (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_class_builder.dart:928:52)
#3      SourceLoader.checkMixins (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_loader.dart:2228:19)
#4      KernelTarget.buildOutlines.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/kernel_target.dart:544:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      withCrashReporting (package:front_end/src/fasta/crash.dart:122:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      IncrementalCompiler.computeDelta.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:400:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      IncrementalCompiler.compile (package:vm/incremental_compiler.dart:68:50)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      FrontendCompiler.compile (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/lib/frontend_server.dart:562:11)

<asynchronous suspension>
#9      listenAndCompile.<anonymous closure> (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/lib/frontend_server.dart:1199:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
2

#0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:264:36)
#1      Class.superclassConstraints (package:kernel/ast.dart:1089:73)
#2      SourceClassBuilder.checkMixinApplication (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_class_builder.dart:928:52)
#3      SourceLoader.checkMixins (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_loader.dart:2228:19)
#4      KernelTarget.buildOutlines.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/kernel_target.dart:544:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      withCrashReporting (package:front_end/src/fasta/crash.dart:122:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      IncrementalCompiler.computeDelta.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:400:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      IncrementalCompiler.compile (package:vm/incremental_compiler.dart:68:50)
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Thanks for comment, but the code is just a default `incrementCounter` actually.

Comment: Do you get this error when running with the Android Emulator?

Comment: Not only with Android Emulator but also with chrome browser or other non-emulator devices

Comment: Did you change the code?

Comment: No I didnt, but firstly I made a new project and did pub get command with another code and it doesnt work so removed the entire project folder, and secondly remade a new project and tried to run with default increment counter code base, but failed in runnnig with the error above.

Comment: and also `flutter doctor` say no issues found.

Comment: I should mention that  if I make any new project, same error exported as above.

Comment: You say the first project doesn't work, do you mean the first project has an error?

Comment: Not only the first project, but also all projects in the same folders has not worked with same error finally.

Comment: What! Sorry, I don't think I can help anymore, I don't think I can fix this error.

Comment: Thanks a lot or do you know how to reinstall flutter or should i do that ?  Just for idea

Comment: You can delete the Flutter folder from anywhere you downloaded and then delete any PATH environment variable you set.

Comment: Thank you before that I will try flutter upgrade first !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried `flutter upgrade --force` and could fix it but finally was not able to specify the reason why it had happened. thanks for your corporation !